# Is there a system-wide way to prevent Num Lock?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My keyboard is configured such that Num Lock replaces certain alphabetical keys with numbers when Num Lock is on. There is also no Num Lock indicator light, which makes Num Lock cause confusion when entering passwords.

I have tried `xmodmap -e 'keycode [Num Lock keycode] = NoSymbol Num_Lock'`, which works fine while in X11. However, it has no effect in tty.

Is there a way to prevent Num Lock from turning on that is system-wide?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Please add as an answer, that method worked nicely. I would prefer if there was a single global way to prevent Num Lock, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: This depends from your operating system.  It's different answers for FreeBSD/TrueOS/DragonFly, NetBSD, and Linux operating systems.  The consequent split between Debian/Ubuntu FreeBSD and Debian/Ubuntu Linux is _further_ complicated by what Debian tries to do with keyboard configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Create ~/.Xmodmap with the following:

```
! -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
! 2014-10-04  
! make num lock do F18  
! keycode  77 = Num_Lock NoSymbol Num_Lock  

clear Lock

keycode 77 = F18 F18 F18
```

Run in terminal:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Comment: The questioner described in the question how to do this with X.  The actual question was how do to this _outwith_ X _as well_.